# DestroyWindow() is not destroying child window

Tags: c, winapi

`WndProc` is the window procedure of the main window. `ChildProc` is the window procedure of the child window. `ChildProc` is not receiving `WM_DESTROY`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: If I remove the `WS_CHILD` window style from `hChild = CreateWindowExW(...);` so it's `hChild = CreateWindowExW(..., WS_VISIBLE, ...);` I do get `WM_DESTROY` in `ChildProc`.

Also, I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2008

```
#include <windows.h>


HINSTANCE g_hInst;


LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            if(hdc)
            {
                RECT rc;
                GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
                SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
                FillRect(hdc, &rc, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_GRAYTEXT));
                TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, TEXT("Child"), 5);
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        MessageBoxW(0, L"Child WM_DESTROY", 0, MB_OK);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hChild;


    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            WNDCLASSEXW wc;
            SecureZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW));
            wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
            wc.hCursor       = LoadCursorW(0, IDC_ARROW);
            wc.hInstance     = g_hInst;
            wc.lpfnWndProc   = ChildProc;
            wc.lpszClassName = L"Childclass////";
            if(!RegisterClassExW(&wc)) return -1;

            hChild = CreateWindowExW(0, L"Childclass////", 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
                0, 0, 200, 100, hwnd, 0, g_hInst, 0);
            if(!hChild) return -1;
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    SecureZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursorW(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIconW(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Mainclass";
    if(!RegisterClassExW(&wc)) return 0;

    g_hInst = hInstance;
    hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, L"Mainclass", L"Main window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 240, 240, 400, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    if(!hwnd) return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: `ChildProc` does not get `WM_QUIT`. The message loop does get `WM_QUIT`

Comment: *The WM_QUIT message is not associated with a window and therefore will never be received through a window's window procedure.*

Comment: why you decide that  child window not receive `WM_DESTROY` ?! only because `MessageBoxW` not shown ? it will be and not shown due `PostQuitMessage(0);` called **before** it. but your child window **receive** `WM_DESTROY`

Comment: you always get `WM_DESTROY`. you simply mistake in diagnostic

Comment: Is there another way to find out I'm getting `WM_DESTROY` in `ChildProc` besides using `MessageBoxW`?

Comment: @Mike32ab: `OutputDebugString()` or write to `stdout` or to a file.  Or to the WIndows event log.  Or `DebugBreak()`.

Comment: or `DbgPrint` - the best way

Comment: `ChildProc` does receive `WM_DESTROY`, I was just doing wrong diagnostics. I tried `HWND h = FindWindowW(0, L"Untitled - Notepad"); if(h) SendMessageW(h, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)L"Test");` in `WM_DESTROY` of `ChildProc` instead and it does work. `MessageBoxW` would show in Windows XP when called in `WM_DESTROY` from the window procedure of a child window though. Thank you all for the comments

Comment: your main error - call `PostQuitMessage` on `WM_DESTROY`. it must be called on `WM_NCDESTROY`

Comment: @Mike32ab: "*I tried `HWND h = FindWindowW(0, L"Untitled - Notepad"); if(h) SendMessageW(h, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)L"Test");` in `WM_DESTROY` of `ChildProc` instead and it does work.*" - a better solution is to use `OutputDebugString()` and then let your debugger display the message. If you don't run the app in a debugger, use [SysInternals DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to see the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you call `DestroyWindow` (assume with valid window handle) - all child windows of course will be destroyed. and all child windows of course received `WM_DESTROY`

> ChildProc is not receiving `WM_DESTROY`.

this is false. i absolute sure it receive it.

> What am I doing wrong?

debug diagnostic and call `PostQuitMessage` from wrong place.

you decide that ChildProc is "not receiving" `WM_DESTROY` only because you not view message box. but it will be just closed, even before shown, if you call `PostQuitMessage(0);` **before** it.

when a window is being destroyed `WM_DESTROY` is sent first to the owned windows (if any), then to window being destroyed and finally to the child windows (if any).

so in case you use child window - first parent window received `WM_DESTROY` and you call `PostQuitMessage` then child window call `MessageBox` which just returned without show due previous `PostQuitMessage` call.

if you use owned window - it receive `WM_DESTROY` first and show `MessageBox` normal. and only after you close it parent window receive `WM_DESTROY` finally and you call `PostQuitMessage`

for fix this, at first need call `PostQuitMessage` from `WM_NCDESTROY` - the parent window receive this message **after** all owned and child windows.

at second the `MessageBox` not the best for debug diagnostic. much better use `DbgPrint`, `OutputDebugString` or breakpoints in debugger

---

thank @RemyLebeau for link to Raymond Chen blog - [why](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393) MessageBox() does not show anything if `PostQuitMessage()` was already called beforehand:

> The other important thing about modality is that a `WM_QUIT` message
>   always breaks the modal loop.

So, if `PostQuitMessage()` is called before `MessageBox()`, the latter will receive the `WM_QUIT` message, cancel its UI, re-post `WM_QUIT`, and exit.

Comment: I was doing wrong diagnostics. You pointed me in the right direction. Thanks for your help

Comment: [Raymond Chen explains](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393) why `MessageBox()` does not show anything if `PostQuitMessage()` was already called beforehand: "*The other important thing about modality is that a `WM_QUIT` message always breaks the modal loop.*" So, if `PostQuitMessage()` is called before `MessageBox()`, the latter will receive the `WM_QUIT` message, cancel its UI, re-post `WM_QUIT`, and exit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, this is obvious :)

Comment: @RbMm: it wasn't obvious to Mike32ab, or he would have already known not to use `MessageBox` in this manner because he would have known that it couldn't display its dialog.